# c++ program stops without errors warnings when printing matrix

Tags: c++

I can't seem to find any solution for this.

I have a type 'route' that contains a matrix.if I do:

```
cout << route << endl;
```

it works it prints the memory
but if I try

```
 cout << route[1][1] << endl;
```

program just ends without any error or anything.
debug says:
"(Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)"

here is the code:

```
//structure is a type I created
Structure ***route = list->searchRoute(startPoint, destination, time);
//should return a matrix
cout << "Avaible routes: \n" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
        cout << route[1][1]->startPoint << endl;
```

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. A [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) would be ideal.

Comment: `Structure ***`, really? What is it that you are doing that needs three levels of indirection?

Comment: "program just ends without error ... SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault". You have a different definition of "without error" than I do.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault usually implies that you are accessing memory you are not supposed to access. What is probably happening is that our "matrix" is probably too small to have a block in the second row/ second column, so an error is thrown when you try to access that location(because you do not own it). Make sure you are allocating route correctly and at the right size.